# Jquery each interation problem

Tags: jquery, iteration, each

I got this random position script. But it works only on the first image... What I'm doing wrong?

```
var randnumsX = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var randnumsY = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$('#obra img').each(function(i,el) {

    m = Math.floor(Math.random()*randnumsX.length);
    randnumsX = randnumsX.splice(m,1);
    posx = Math.floor(m * 50);

    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*randnumsY.length);
    randnumsY = randnumsY.splice(n,1);
    posy = Math.floor(n * 50);

    $(el).css({position:'absolute', left: posx + 155, top: posy});      
    $(el).fadeIn('slow');

});
```

Comment: What does your markup look like? Are all the images within a single div with the id="div"?

Comment: if you debug...does it even loop? I mean, how many images are there the collection retrieved by $('div img')?

Comment: Fixed code, but still not working. The markup is right. I got one div (#obra) with 5 images inside. I want to randomize the positions without repeat the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) returns the removed element not the array with the element removed.

Comment: Replacing `randnumsX = randnumsX.splice(m,1);` with `randnumsX.splice(m,1);` would do the trick. Also note that the similarly-named `slice()` method does not modify the array the way `splice()` does -- watch for typos.

Comment: x = randnumsX.splice(m,1); posx = Math.floor(x*50);

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the div then you won't need # sign

```
$('div img').each(function(i,el) {

m = Math.floor(Math.random()*randnumsX.length);
randnumsX = randnumsX.splice(m,1);
posx = Math.floor(m * 50);

n = Math.floor(Math.random()*randnumsY.length);
randnumsY = randnumsY.splice(n,1);
posy = Math.floor(n * 50);

$(el).css({position:'absolute', left: posx + 155, top: posy});      
$(el).fadeIn('slow');
```

});

Comment: Hi Meenakshi, fixed on the original post.